# Braintree and credit card payment from mobile app

Tags: braintree, braintree-vault

I am working on an app that requires payment to be collected from customers. I have few questions related to braintree integration with my app. I am actually struggling a bit with the workings of the braintree so thought of checking here.

1. The PCI compliance is critical so i do not want to store anything in my app or the backend server. Can I achieve this with braintree? I also don’t want customer to retype the credit card information when they come back to the app. As I understand there is a Vault functionality which can do this but I was not sure.
2. Do I invoke the braintree API from iOS app directly or do I need to first send the credit card information to my backend layer and then invoke the Braintree APIs from backend. I don’t want to transmit anything to my server due to the PCI compliance so I am hoping that I can just invoke the braintree API directly from the iOS APP and when user comes back, again invoke the braintree Vault API from the APP and pull the previously used credit card.
3. appreciate if anyone can pls. direct me to some kind of architecture / white paper/best practice on this. I went thru the APIs document on braintree site which provides and good API documents but i could not find the high level architecture document on this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question as asked may be a bit too broad for SO.  Also, question #3 asks for off-site resources that would be primarily opinion-based (so that one is specifically off-topic for SO).  You might want to check out the "How to Ask" page in the Help Center - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Also, check out the "Tour" page: http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  The specificity and detail in the question directly affects the relevance and quality of any answers might get.

Comment: I work at Braintree. I'd suggest you [contact our support team](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654248/braintree-and-credit-card-payment-from-mobile-app) to get help with these issues; they're a bit detailed for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: thanks agf.. i will be contacting support team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the heart of this question must inherently require official documentation to obtain an answer due to PCI compliance for a web API.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview
2. Yes use from iOS.  https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/start/hello-client

for number three... I'm not sure where to find that. Definitely ask support